# QNAP - When reday?

Tags: nas, qnap

I have transferred 450 GB with tons of small files to my QNAP NAS TS-231k. The copy finished successfully, but it is still working since 2 days continuously.

1. How can I see what QNAP is doing?
2. Is there a way to see when the process is ready?
3. Can I interrupt the process?

Edit:
The firmware on NAS ist QTS 5.0.1.2376
I copied from w10/64 with the Explorer via LAN and finished successfully two day ago.

Comment: What is your OS? How are you transferring the data?

Comment: I added information in the question.

Comment: Are you on Windows and have copied using Explorer ?

Comment: Yes, I copied from W10/64 with the explorer.

Comment: copy or cut / paste?

Comment: copy, not cut and paste! Please note that the copy is finished succesfully but the NAS is still running.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I see what QNAP is doing?

You can open another instance of Explorer and see how much was copied.

Explorer itself will display while copying a status dialog that shows
how much was copied and how much is left. The dialog also includes
an estimate for the time left (which is unreliable).

> Is there a way to see when the process is ready?

The only way is when the status dialog disappears.

> Can I interrupt the process?

You may interrupt the process at any time by clicking the Cancel button.

The files that have been fully copied are not removed.
If the current file that was being copied is interrupted this way, it may
be truncated to as much data as was already copied.

Note that Explorer is perhaps the slowest copy software in existence.
I would recommend using a utility such as `robocopy` for this operation
or an alternate program specializing in fast copy, for example the free
[FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/) (but there are many such).